# My otherwise monogamous friends came to the party with their wives

Tags: syntax, latin, germanic-languages, agreement

Romance languages (French, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese) tend to say that "My friends came with their wife, who were all blowing their nose." (no polygamy, a cold epidemic but no monstrosity either), whereas Germanic langagues tend to say that "My friends came with their wives, who were all blowing their noses." (!) Any explanation for the difference? Which is more represented in the Indo-European family of languages? Which would be the original way of seeing things and which a contamination by another family of languages?
"Mes amis sont venus avec leur femme, qui toutes faisaient trompeter leur nez." ('blowing their noses' would be 'qui toutes se mouchaient' without any mention of the nose; that is why I chose 'qui toutes faisaient trompeter leur nez' which is not common at all but has the merit of including the word nose, in the singular, of course)
I know I would write 'avec leur femme' even though following it with a verb in the plural does look strange, less so, however, if you add 'toutes', the way I did in the edited version.

Comment: Position is very important. If the other noun is far away from the first noun, then the number of the other noun is more flexible. "Wife" would seem impossible in the English example, but "nose" would be fine.

Comment: "Their nose" works (after a manner) because in a certain register of English "their" is used to mean "his or her". But this is an entirely different issue.

Comment: Hungarian language generally uses singulars, but there is one counterexample in the Arany János ballad „Szondi két apródja”.

Comment: As a native Spanish speaker, not so sure: if I listen "Pedro, Juan y José vinieron con su esposa" I analyze it to mean only one of them brought his wife (who?), whereas "[...] vinieron con sus esposas" is much clearer. You could be even more specific adding "respectivas" or "sendas" before "esposas", to emphasize each friend came with his respective wife :)

Comment: There are two potentially separate questions here, the number of 'wife' and that of 'nose'. Re the former at least I think you're wrong that it's singular in Romance: I'm fairly competent in French and Spanish (though not native in either) and would certainly say/write *avec leurs femmes* and *con sus mujeres*; the singular here looks wrong to me.

Comment: I agree with Joe Pineda's judgment for Spanish.

Comment: I would like to know the source for this claim since, as far as I can tell, it is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In French you can write either “leur femme” or “leurs femmes”; both are considered correct. It is purely an orthographic issue, as the pronunciation is the same in both cases. But to write “leur femme (sing.), qui faisaient (pl.)” seems to me enormously illogical.

In Latin I would definitely say “Venerunt amici cum suis uxoribus”; to say “cum sua uxore” is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "It is purely an orthographic issue, as the pronunciation is the same in both cases": *leur femme* and *leurs femmes* are pronounced the same, but the issue also affects phrases that aren't, such as *leur épouse* vs. *leurs épouses*.

Comment: "leurs femmes" is correct? says who?

Comment: @user58319, see this article in Le Figaro http://www.lefigaro.fr/lefigaromagazine/2011/01/08/01006-20110108ARTFIG00600-mussolini-hitler-mao-bokassa-ces-dictateurs-tyrannises-par-leurs-femmes.php

Comment: In this article, 'leurs femmes' might very well mean each of the dictator had more than one, successively!